# Can't configure tomcat access log session id with %S

Tags: tomcat, logging, sessionid

In tomcat 7, one is supposed to be able to add the user session id to the access log by adding "%S" to the access log valve pattern. However, this isn't working for me. All I'm getting is a "-" in the log instead of the expected long hex string.

Is there some trick to this? Or is it a bug?

Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score -1):

You need to use realm with some user database. Read docs here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

If your authentication is propietary (your own jsp/servlets and logic), then Tomcat container can't handle user session.

Example: you can use JOSSO, CAS or embedded Tomcat SSO agent to manage user sessions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that's correct. We use proprietary authentication with user sessions all the time. The session key is in the browser cookie and is accessible to code. I just want it in the logs. -- FT

Comment: @FredToth Session and Authentication are different things. Only if Tomcat knows you are using authentication could show this property in the logs. The same thing happen using Apache Server. More info here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072850/java-security/j2ee-security--container-versus-custom.html

Comment: @fredtoth I agree, at the end what you need is a session in your server (with authentication or not). However, session exist ususally when using authentication.